# zdiff on compressed files created from the same file

Tags: bash, gzip, diff

I did the following:

```
$ echo hello > file1    
$ tar -czvf file1.tgz file1
file1    
$ tar -czvf file1234 file1
file1    
$ zdiff file1234 file1.tgz 
Binary files file1234 and - differ
```

Just wondering why zdiff reports a difference?

Answer (score 1):

From `zdiff` manpage:

> CAVEATS
>
> zcmp and zdiff rely solely on the file extension to determine what is, or is not, a compressed file.

So, you're comparing the gzipped contents of `file1234` to the decompressed contents of `file1.tgz` (as I believe you can see in the filenames, `-` being the decompression stream).

Comment: I'm on a Mac, I have this man page: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/zdiff.1.html